# eclipse auto getter and setter method in other method

Tags: java, eclipse, optimization, getter-setter

This is simple class implementation

```
class A{
private int a;
public void doSomething() {
    a = 5;
    int b = a;
    /*.
      .
      . */
}
/*
.
.
. */
}
```

now i'm using eclipse CTRL + 1 quick fix keybind and insert get and set mothod and codes will be this and this is option 1

```
class A{
private int a;
public void doSomething() {
    setA(5);
    int b = getA();
    /*.
      .
      . */
}
/*
.
.
. */
public int getA() {
    return a;
}
public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}
}
```

but if i want keep field codes will be this.(option 2)

```
class A{
private int a;
public void doSomething() {
    a = 5;
    int b = a;;
    /*.
      .
      . */
}
/*
.
.
. */
public int getA() {
    return a;
}
public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}
}
```

so which option is better for oop or code organization.

Comment: This may matter if your setter does more than just set, and these possible other behaviors include checking for appropriateness of the parameter, or throwing a property change event for any listeners that are interested in changes in a's state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the normal assignment of `a` (i.e. `a = 5;`) inside `doSomething` instead of using the setter (`setA(5)`), try creating the getters and setters using the refactoring key binding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and then select "Generate Getters and Setters".

If the only thing the setter does is assign the value to the field, there should be no difference between the two options.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, then you could make `int setA(int)` also `return a;`, and then you can "chain" the method calls

```
public int setA(int a) {
  this.a = a;
  return a;
}

public void doSomething() {
  int b = setA(5);
}
```